Querying a pandas dataframe efficiently
Here's the MRE that produces expected results:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "A": [1, 2, 3],
    "B": [100, 200, 300]
}

s = {100, 300, 500}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for _, row in df.query("B in @s").iterrows():
    print(row["A"])

Output:
1
3

In other words, what I want is all the column "A" values where the corresponding column "B" values occur in a set.
Although this code works, I can't help thinking that it's a little cumbersome. Is there a more concise/efficient way to achieve this?

out = df.loc[df['B'].isin(s), 'A']

Or just select column 'A' afterwards: df.query("B in @s")['A'] (series), df.query("B in @s")[['A']] (df).

@PandaKim Thank you for your comment and enhancing my knowledge of pandas (which is severely lacking). Please consider proposing your comment as an answer. Also worth mentioning that thsi technique is significantly faster then my naive approach

@SIGHUP I'm posting this as a comment rather than an answer because I think there are many similar questions in SO. It would have been nice to find a similar question and link to it, but I'm not a native english, so I just left the code as a comment rather than an answer.
